# custom biber bibliography: dot before numbering

Tags: biblatex

I was trying to change the bibliography style used by `biblatex` for article (it printed too many stuff for my taste). But somehow I get a very weird dot before the numbers in the list. What am I doing wrong and how could I fix that? See MWE and output for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=ydnt,backend=biber,maxnames=10,defernumbers,date=year]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@Article{Ferdinandy2015,
  Title                    = {HIV competition dynamics over sexual networks: first comer advantage conserves founder effects.},
  Author                   = {Ferdinandy, Bence and Mones, Enys and Vicsek, Tam{\'{a}}s and M{\"{u}}ller, Viktor},
  Journal                  = {PLoS Comput Biol},
  Year                     = {2015}
}
@article{Ferdinandy20121207,
title = "Landing together: How flocks arrive at a coherent action in time and space in the presence of perturbations ",
journal = "Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications ",
volume = "391",
number = "4",
pages = "1207 - 1215",
year = "2012"
}
@article{1,
title = "Landing together: How flocks arrive at a coherent action in time and space in the presence of perturbations ",
journal = "Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications ",
volume = "391",
number = "4",
pages = "1207 - 1215",
year = "2011"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \printnames{author}\setunit{\space}%
  \printfield{title}\setunit{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%

  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
  }


\begin{document}
\section{publications}
\nocite{*}
\defbibheading{empty}{}
\subsection{papers}
\printbibliography[heading=empty, type=article, resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Properly set the end of an entry with `\usebibmacro{finentry}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, that actually solved it. Is there a good tutorial for this somewhere? I find navigating the biber documentation very hard without much prior knowledge

Comment: Get into the source, especially `standard.bbx` and look how the authors designed the entries. I find this very helpful.

Comment: @Johannes_B Want to write up an answer here then? You might want to mention that there are more elegant and less dangerous (and radical) ways to suppress information in the bibliography.

Comment: @moewe To be honest, i am ok with how it is done here. Clearing fields seems to be tedious in this case. Can you write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Maybe you are right seeing how much information was indeed omitted here. Since you found the real cause of the trouble here, I would feel much more comfortable with you writing that answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B Hello again! Would you mind writing down an answer here?

Comment: @moewe Done, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to end an entry properly. `biblatex` provides the macros `finentry` for exactly that purpose.

The vertical space between entries can be set with `\bibitemsep`.

[image: fbenceBiblatexFinentry]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{Ferdinandy2015,
        Title                    = {HIV competition dynamics over sexual networks: first comer advantage conserves founder effects.},
        Author                   = {Ferdinandy, Bence and Mones, Enys and Vicsek, Tam{\'{a}}s and M{\"{u}}ller, Viktor},
        Journal                  = {PLoS Comput Biol},
        Year                     = {2015}
    }
    @article{Ferdinandy20121207,
        title = "Landing together: How flocks arrive at a coherent action in time and space in the presence of perturbations ",
        journal = "Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications ",
        volume = "391",
        number = "4",
        pages = "1207 - 1215",
        year = "2012"
    }
    @article{1,
        title = "Landing together: How flocks arrive at a coherent action in time and space in the presence of perturbations ",
        journal = "Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications ",
        volume = "391",
        number = "4",
        pages = "1207 - 1215",
        year = "2011"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \printnames{author}\setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{title}\setunit{\space}%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibitemsep}{2\baselineskip}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```